# There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this issue in yellow color when i compiling a react project, but the followin thing thisturbs me a lot

> WARNING in ./node_modules/React/cjs/react.development.js
>   There are multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This
>   can lead to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with
>   other case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module
>   identifiers:
>   * C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\React\cjs\react.development.js
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\React\index.js
>   * C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\react\cjs\react.development.js
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\react\index.js
>   @ ./node_modules/React/cjs/react.development.js  @
>   ./node_modules/React/index.js  @ ./src/widgets/components/modal.js  @
>   ./src/pages/containers/home.js  @ ./src/entries_points/home.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000
>   ./src/entries_points/home.js
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/React/cjs/react.production.min.js There are
>   multiple modules with names that only differ in casing. This can lead
>   to unexpected behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other
>   case-semantic. Use equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\React\cjs\react.production.min.js
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\React\index.js
>   * C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\react\cjs\react.production.min.js
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\react\index.js
>   @ ./node_modules/React/cjs/react.production.min.js  @
>   ./node_modules/React/index.js  @ ./src/widgets/components/modal.js  @
>   ./src/pages/containers/home.js  @ ./src/entries_points/home.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000
>   ./src/entries_points/home.js
>
> WARNING in ./node_modules/React/index.js There are multiple modules
>   with names that only differ in casing. This can lead to unexpected
>   behavior when compiling on a filesystem with other case-semantic. Use
>   equal casing. Compare these module identifiers:
>   * C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\React\index.js
>       Used by 1 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--0!C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\src\widgets\components\modal.js
>   * C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\react\index.js
>       Used by 15 module(s), i. e.
>       C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\node_modules\babel-loader\lib\index.js??ref--0!C:\cygwin64\home\waysolutions-soft\curso\nodejs\react\src\entries_points\home.js
>   @ ./node_modules/React/index.js  @ ./src/widgets/components/modal.js 
>   @ ./src/pages/containers/home.js  @ ./src/entries_points/home.js  @
>   multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:9000
>   ./src/entries_points/home.js

the project in the web browser runs perfectly, but i dont know how to correct this thing, im on windows 10 d: , i read that is a windows problem but i want to fix it.
regards

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You're importing classes with different cases than it's export, please check your import statements.

Comment: you can give me an example please? :), im new in this

Comment: `import React from 'react';` 
vs 
`import React from 'React'; `
The latter is a wrong import.

Comment: sorry im two years and a half late, that was correct

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error using Nuxt.js. The reason seemed to be the folder `components/Global`.

I found the components inside this folder added to `.nuxt\components\index.js` once as `Compname` and once as `GlobalCompname`.

The error went away after moving the components into the `components` folder.

Renaming the folder to `components/_global` also worked (first attempt).

The answers in https://forum.vuejs.org/t/resolved-there-are-multiple-modules-with-names-that-only-differ-in-casing/26627/6 got me thinking about the path and that maybe `Global` might be reserved or something.